# How to do to be able to write on the chip

Tags: rfid, codesys

I use an IO LINK RFID reader with an EtherCAT controller in Codesys. In the process data, only the chip ID of RF-HDT-DVBB-N2 chip is being read, but I have no access to other commands for writing or reading. These commands are not functioning at all only the id . I noticed there is a flag that should have the 7th bit set to 1. I set this in ProzessdataOut, and the 7th bit corresponds to the write command, but it doesn't work at all. The user memory of the chips is not user or factory locked. it would be very kind if you could help. How can this issue in Codesys be resolved, and be able to write on the chip

i expected to use the commands of write and read not only Read ID command